# QTreeWidget fill from thread Item expanded

Tags: c++, qt

I fill my QTreeWidget out of a thread. Works well so far, but after he data is populated, all items are not expanded but they are available. All items I added I set `...setExpanded(true);`

This cause at the end the problem, that `treeCount()` is 1.

I want to avoid to set in constructer `expandAll` and I also want to avoid to make an extra List to count the items.

If I start the fill method from common app thread as a simple function, everything I `...setExpanded(true);` is expanded after populate.

I there a trick to avoid this problem?

Comment: It would be very useful to see a [mcve] if possible, or at least the relevant code blocks

Answer (score 1):

Never mangle with a QObject from a different thread. All GUI object operations need to be done in the same thread.

Use a signal/slot mechanism between your threads to communicate new items. Alternatively, set up a new Q*ItemModel in the extra thread and pass it once in a signal.

Comment: I thought that "Data" operation on the TreeWidget is an operation to its model and not to its style. If I create. model in the thread and sign this model with emit to the tree widget isn't this the same?

Comment: The TreeWidget accesses the model with direct function calls. The model has to reside in same thread as the widget. When you pass a new model to the other thread, you can use moveToThread() accordingly.